# Google Script Date Showing wrong "hours"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dst, timezone-offset

I feel as if I have poured over nearly all of the documentation regarding dates in JS and GAS. Especially concerning DST issues. Since I have not had a problem like this until the DST change. I think I am missing something simple. The problem is that despite messing with all of the settings the hours on my date output from the format utility are still incorrect. Below is a screen shot of the debugger and a snippet of the code i am running. 
The value 'date' is the one that I am concerned with. It is created within the script on line 53.

```
var date = new Date(); //line 53
date = Utilities.formatDate(date, "Chicago/America", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"); //line 61
```

I am based in KC. (Central Time or UTC-06:00 or whatever).

I have a feeling this is going to be a face palm moment for me but oh well!
Thank you for any and all help!

[image: Debugging output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I usually use without any issue is simply that :

```
  var FUS1=new Date(dateObject).toString().substr(25,6)+":00";// get the timeZone part of the string coming from the date you are working on (an event)
  dateString = Utilities.formatDate(dateObject, FUS1, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");// use it in formatDate and it will have the right value for every season...
```

note that you were using `date` 2 times in your example code :once as a string result and once as a date object in the same line...

Edit following your comment :

assuming for example that the datestamp is in A2, the following code should return the right time.

```
  var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').getValue();
  var FUS1=new Date(date).toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
  dateString = Utilities.formatDate(date, FUS1, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: hmmm. So in the first line how did you define the _dateObject?_

Comment: sorry, I didn't see you comment... I called it dateObject to point the difference versus dateString, it could come from a calendar event or a spreadsheet cell or whatever... When you use new Date() you create a date object, if you use utilities.formatDate.... you get a date string. you can't do the same with each of them. When you have to write a date in a spreadsheet you should use a date object and let the spreadsheet show it the way you want. A string is not very useful since you can only display it... Could you give more information about what you are using this for ?

Comment: Hmm okay I think I understand now.  
`var date = new Date(); //creates new date object  
var datestring = Utilities.formatDate(date,"Chicago/America", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); //returns date-string`  
My output however is still and incorrectly formatted date-string and the date object is not taking into account the DST change when using the above two lines. I am seeing:  date = Thu Mar 14 2013 12:19:27 GMT-6:00 (CST)  datestring = "03/14/2013 18:19:27" //wth is with the 18 for hours?? –

Comment: As far as more information the script itself is being used to get the time stamp of the latest submission on a form. I was getting some very strange dates back so I was testing and came across this.

The bigger issue with this is that I am using the _formatDate_ method to try and format a regular string. I will just have to format the string like I would any other.

Comment: hmmm well actually now that I tried a few other things it seems like when I use _getValue()_ to get the time stamp from the spreadsheet it does return a dateObject.... So now I am thinking that the _formatDate()_ method is to blame for the messed up date strings.

Comment: No I don't think that is working out. The first line returns a range object which is being passed the the _new Date()_ method and to the _formatDate()_ method, neither of these are valid arguments for the functions.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, I forgot the getValue()

Comment: glad it helped and thanks ! btw, keep this FUS1 trick in mind as it will probably serve you a lot ;-), it does for me...

Comment: @Sergeinsas What's FUS1 actually stand for?  This seems like the way to detect the user's timezone in the browser if the date box value is run through a server handler, is it not?

Comment: in a way it is... it is a way to get the timezone of the event rather than the timezone of the user. It is mainly useful when dealing with calendar events and daylight savings (sometimes the event tz and the user tz are not the same because of daylight savings).