# Changing Time Zone to EST

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, gmt

Good Morning, I am using the code below that someone lovingly provided online, to create "backups" or copies of a google sheet each night. The issue is that the timestamp is in GMT and I really need it to be in EST (New York). Can someone please tell me how to fix this? I am a total novice

Link to original: https://gist.github.com/abhijeetchopra/99a11fb6016a70287112

ISSUE AREA:
generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

I tired typing EST, typing -5:00, the time did not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, typing "EST" or "-5:00" didn't do anything because they're not the format `Utilities.formatDate()` is looking for.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597149/7528454) you need to use [formats available here](https://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

This should achieve what you're after:

`Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "US/Eastern", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");`

or

`Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/New_York", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");`

Note that `"GMT"` worked originally as it is listed as an alias on the formats page, but EST is not.

**Further Reading**

[similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22566370/7528454)

[google ads scripting documentation on dates, but should be mostly transferrable!](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates)

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked, this was my first time using google scripts. I tried to read through the forums but it seemed like every other question and method  was so complicated to get the end result

Comment: @AshleyP Glad you got it sorted! And agreed, the issue of formatting is obscured by the use of functions to dynamically set the timezone in most answers.  I couldn't even find reference to the formatting in the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format